# How to compress class values in WEKA explorer

Tags: machine-learning, weka

Hello I am new to WEKA and am using weka 3.6.10.

Sorry if the answer to this question is something obvious.

I have a dataset containing 10 attributes and one decision class. Decision class is composed of values {1,2,3,4}, is there a way to change configuration so that the values would be considered as {1} and {2,3,4}(binary) rather than each of the values separately without modifying the other attributes?
I had a look at the WEKA filter but did not find anything useful.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an Unsupervised Attribute filter, e.g. the NumericToBinary filter. In the topmost field of the configuration dialog, enter the posistion of the "Decision class" attribute. If it is in the 8th column, enter 8.

The filter will create "dummy variable" columns for each unique value of this attribute. If there are 4 unique values, after applying this filter your dataset will have 4 additional columns. Remove 3 of them.

Comment: Apparently the decision class is Nominal for some reason. I tried following the steps but I can only see one field in the configuration dialog(ignoreClass field). I think I could use NominalToBinary but how would I go about applying it only on the class?

Comment: Ah, I forgot that some filters ignore the class attribute. You have to temporarily assign a differwnt attribute as the class atribute:  In the select box above the histogram, select Class: myDecisionclass, assign some other attribute as the class, apply the NumericToBinary Filter on myDecisionclass (which is now a regualar attribute), re-assign the class attribute to its old attribute. (Depending on the algorithm chosen, maybe you have to re-apply the BinaryToNominal filter)

Comment: Thanks I figured it out now